# StringBuilder append "," basic concern

Tags: java, string, append, stringbuilder

I have a code like:

```
projsForWhichPermCheckFailedSBuilder.append(currentProject.getDisplayString()).append(", ");
```

This is dynamic append and above code is in for loop... so at last I want to remove extra ", ", I have done something like:

```
projsForWhichPermCheckFailedString = projsForWhichPermCheckFailedSBuilder.substring(0, projsForWhichPermCheckFailedSBuilder.length()-2);
```

Please suggest some better way!!! Thanks...

Comment: Are we talking about C# ? Are you appending data separated by a given delimiter ?

Comment: Hi , I am working in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your input looks like, but let's say for the sake of an example, the input is a collection of String objects, e.g. `List<String> input` and given:

```
final String delimiter = ",";
```

then you could use one of the following approaches ...

**Using Java StringBuilder class.**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : input)
{
    sb.append("s").append(delimiter);
}

if (sb.toString().endsWith(delimiter))
{
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
// Results in output: s,s,s
```

**Using Guava (see [Strings Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained) for a full example).**

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add("1");
input.add("2");
input.add("3");

final String result = Joiner.on(delimiter).join(input);
System.out.println(result);
// Results in output: 1,2,3
```